# Leap Motion SwipeGesture

Tags: gesture, gestures, leap-motion

I am looking into the leap motion controller. I want to integrate the leap motion controller into my app for the sole reason of gestures -- up, down, left, right.

Will [SwipeGesture](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/api/Leap.SwipeGesture.html) be the correct method to use? Do people have trouble using it? (i.e., does it work only half the time?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swipe gestures are pretty robust. You can set parameters for minimum speed and length before a swipe gesture will be recognized to fine tune things for your app (except in JavaScript, where this isn't supported).

The Swipe gesture is probably the easiest way, but you could also do your own recognition using the hand and finger positions also provided by the API.